# Eigen: Operating on Vectors of Different Types

Tags: c++, vectorization, eigen

I have many expressions that look like

```
auto result = vec3f.cwiseProduct( vec3ui );
```

where `vec3f` is from type `Eigen::Matrix< float, 3, 1 >` and `vec3ui` is from `Eigen::Matrix< unsigned int, 3, 1 >`.
These doesn't seem to be allowed, at least the compiler complains about it.

Hence I need to write the above like

```
Eigen::Matrix< float, 3, 1 > result( vec3f.x() * vec3ui.x(), /*...*/ );
```

which leads to very long, less-readable code.

Is it possible to vectorize the above expression using Eigen 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the second matrix to the form of the first, like this:

```
Eigen::Matrix< float, 3, 1 > mf;
Eigen::Matrix< unsigned int, 3, 1 > mi;
mf.dot(mi.cast<float>());
```

Also, Eigen gives ready to use types for vectors, like `Eigen::Vector3f` for floats and `Eigen::Vector3i` for ints. (but none for `unsigned int`)